# How to delete a particular field record on access database

Tags: vb.net

I wonder to know how to delete a particular field record

```
ds_Subject.Tables("iswe").Rows(0).Item(2).Delete()
```

This is what I've tried but it gave me an error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Public member 'Delete' on type 'DBNull' not found.

Answer (score 2):

You can only delete a row.

```
 ds_Subject.Tables("iswe").Rows(0).Delete()
```

If you want to change the contents of a particular column, do an assignment

```
 ds_Subject.Tables("iswe").Rows(0)("columnname") = <your value>
```